# how to pass body type in Karate feature file?

Tags: api, automation, frameworks, karate

I am new one for api automation and Karate framework, I have been asked to automate a GET request with Body Type = 'x-www-form-urlencoded' and other parameters(cannot share owing to security constraint), I have tried the below option but getting an error stating "no step-definition method match found for: Body Content-Type = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8'

Following is the .Feature file contents that I have tried:

```
**Feature: First demo API 
  Scenario: API demo try
    Given url '{Given_url}'
    And Body Content-Type = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8' 
    And Body {Grant_type:Value, scope:value}
    when method GET
    Then status 200**
```

I have even tried just passing the Body Type as 'x-www-form-urlencoded;charset' but still getting the same issue. Please help me and thanks in advance.

Regards,
V.Prashanth

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong. Read the docs please: https://github.com/intuit/karate#header

```
And header Content-Type = 'blah'
And request { Grant_type: 'Value', scope: 'value' }
```

Comment: Please help me on another issue, I am running a Json request and getting the Test result as "Pass / Fail" while passing in required parameters, but I am not able to get the Json response which I get in "Postman". can you please let me know is there any reason?.

Comment: absolutely no idea at all. maybe you should just stick to Postman ;)

Comment: Following is the Request I am trying                                                                  
  **Feature: First demo API 
  Scenario: API demo try
    Given url '{Given_url}
And header Content-Type = 'blah'
And request { Grant_type: 'Value', scope: 'value' }
when method GET
    Then status 200*  - This is the same Json file I am passing in as Request. Thanks in advance!! plz help.

Comment: time for you to follow this process. all the best ! https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue